# want to send an email through cloud functions using sendgrid

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I am sending an email to a person whose data is updated which is stored in google firestore, using cloud functions. I am using sendgrid to send email.

My cloud function is working fine, whenever I update the data it gets triggered. But I am unable to send email.

```
const sendgridemail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
const MY_SENDGRID_API_KEY = '<API key>'
sendgridemail.setApiKey(MY_SENDGRID_API_KEY);
exports.helloFirestore = (event, callback) => {
const triggerResource = event.resource;
console.log('Function triggered by change to: ' +  triggerResource);
console.log(JSON.stringify(event));

 const msgbody = {
                    to: 'laaaf09@gmail.com',
                    from: 'abc@nnn.co',
                    subject:  'database updated - xyzshopping.com',
                    templateId: '<template ID>',
 }
return helloFirestore.send(msgbody)

            .then(() => console.log('payment mail sent success') )
            .catch(err => console.log(err) )
             callback();


};
```

I have deployed the code from console using inline editor and zip upload also.
It is getting triggered but not sending email.It is throwing me error:

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.sendgrid.com api.sendgrid.com:443 at
>   errnoException (dns.js:28:10) at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as
>   oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26) code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
>   syscall: 'getaddrinfo', hostname: 'api.sendgrid.com', host:
>   'api.sendgrid.com', port: 443

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to call `callback()` only after all the async work is done.  You're calling it before the work even starts.  That's certainly not going to work.  From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background):

> **callback**
>
> A callback to signal completion of the function's execution.

You've signaled the end of the function prematurely.  You should only call it after the work completes, both in the `then` and `catch` callbacks of the async work.